# The car registration number is being printed into a file in the wrong way (not the way i want it to)

Tags: python-3.x

I need help in my car registration number plate being written in a file(only those that have broken the speed limit). My code partly works, but i am having troubles with the registration plate... it only prints one out the many that have broken the speed limit. Also, i need it to be in different lines. This is my code(thank you in advance):

```
varlimit = 70
import time
import re
def speedcam():
criminallist = []

print (' ')
regpat = "[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]\s[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"
reg = input('Insert your registration number: ')

while re.match(regpat, reg):
    print ('Your registration number is: ',reg)
    time.sleep(2)
    print (' ')
    time_taken = float(input('Enter time taken: '))
    print ('The time taken is: {:.2f} minutes'.format(time_taken))
    distance = float(input('Enter distance: '))
    print ('The distance is: {:.2f} ' .format(distance) ,'miles')
    speed_limit = distance / (time_taken / 60)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(' ')
    print ('The speed limit is: {:.2f}' .format(speed_limit) , 'mph')
    time.sleep(1)

    if speed_limit > varlimit:
        print ('Your registration number, "',reg , '" has been forwarded to the police"')
        criminallist.append(reg)

    file = open("speeders.txt","w")
    file.write = (criminallist+'\n')
    file.close()

    if speed_limit < varlimit:
        print ('You drive well. thank you for following the rules.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print (' ')

    question = input('Do you want to continue? (Y/N) :')
    if question == 'Y':
        print (' ')
        speedcam()
    if question == 'N':
        print ('--Program Terminated--')
        print (' ')
        print (' ')
        print ('Now printing list of cars breaking the speed limt.')
        print (' ')
        print ('  LIST OF CARS BREAKING THE SPEED LIMIT OR WITH INVALID REGISTRATION NUMBERS:')

    print (criminallist)



else:
    print ('Your registration number, ',reg , 'is invalid, and it has been forwarded to the police')
    criminallist.append(reg)

    question = input('Do you want to continue? (Y/N) :')
    if question == 'Y':
        print (' ')
        speedcam()
    if question == 'N':
        print ('--Program Terminated--')
        print (' ')
        print (' ')
        print ('Now printing list of cars breaking the speed limt.')
        print (' ')
        print ('  LIST OF CARS BREAKING THE SPEED LIMIT OR WITH INVALID REGISTRATION NUMBERS:')

    print (criminallist)

    file = open("speeders.txt","w")
    file.write = (criminallist+'\n')
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `w` when you open the file for writing, but `w` truncates the file and starts over.  You probably want `a` for appending, instead.